# Caretaker and caregiver - linguistic and logical nonsense

Tags: word-meaning, difference

today I would like to ask for something strange that seems to me very strange, I dare to say as (linguistic and logical) nonsense.

---

**Base:**

**Caregiver** is OK. It says that somebody gives (provides) care to somebody else.

**Caretaker** sounds like if it should say that somebody takes (gains) care from somebody else. But however, it says that somebody gives (provides) to somebody else - too.

---

**Examples:** (that I was able to quickly remember)

**Caregiver** is word used mostly for some (lower ranked, if I could say from my own experience with this job) social services employees.

**Caretaker** is name of the being (with whom staff of USS Voyager NCC-74656 in the beginning of TV series Star Trek - Voyager) that protected and cared of the nation on surface of one planet. Alternative backward translation of its name used in my language is *protector*.

Comment: A ***caretaker*** is a person who ***takes care** of something / someone* (usually, a thing rather than a person). But a ***caregiver*** is normally restricted to  contexts where "care and attention" is given / made available to a ***person*** (you don't have a *caregiver* to look after the plumbing and such in a tenement black, for example, only a *caretaker*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logical nonsense perhaps.  Most language is illogical.

"Caretaker" is a fairly old word, it means someone who "takes care" of a house or particularly a school. It could, I suppose, be generalised in a story to someone who takes care of a whole planet.  You should understand "care" here means "charge, oversight, attention or heed with a view to safety or protection" (etymolonline) and had a rather negative connotation. The idiom "to take care of" dates from the sixteenth century, and you should compare it with "take in hand" or "take a view of".

"Caregiver" is a more recent word, in its current sense of someone who cares for a elderly or sick person, particularly a relative, or perhaps a person employed by social services. This is related to a positive sense of "care" which developed alongside the negative one, and which gives the verb "to care" a positive sense.

The word "care" has several meanings. And it is completely illogical that "caregiver" and "caretaker" should have similar meanings, but language is not logical.